# Difference between archive manager and the command 'ar'

Tags: package-management, file-roller

I'm in the early stages of attempting to learn packaging for Debian/Ubuntu, and I am following [this guide](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Debian-Binary-Package-Building-HOWTO/) to package a collection of binaries (that I've obtained by using Alien to break apart an rpm package).

As suggested in step 3, you can look at package contents (for an example I'll use chromium) using this command:

```
$ ar tv /var/cache/apt/archives/chromium-browser_37.0.2062.120-0ubuntu0.14.04.1~pkg1049_amd64.deb
```

Which returns:

```
rw-r--r-- 0/0      4 Sep 17 00:45 2014 debian-binary
rw-r--r-- 0/0   5220 Sep 17 00:45 2014 control.tar.gz
rw-r--r-- 0/0 46696752 Sep 17 00:47 2014 data.tar.xz
```

The package looks like this though when opened through the archive manager:

[image: Chromium package opened in archive manager]

As you can see, the contents appear to be absolutely different (though I expected them to be the same). What is it that I don't understand about the Archive Manager and/or the `ar` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Archive Manager processes files a bit so that you don't see it as is, but in a more human-friendly form.

For example, you see the contents of the `tar` archive in a `tar.gz` file, instead of seeing the `tar` archive itself, like you would if you opened it in 7zip in Windows.

I would have guessed it used [`libarchive`](http://www.libarchive.org/) but I am wrong.

It uses `dpkg-deb` to process Debian packages, a feature introduced in version [2.31.3](http://fileroller.sourceforge.net/news.html):

> - Use dpkg-deb to view and extract .deb files. (Josselin Mouette) ([#576436](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=576436))

This was done in response to a [feature request](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=576436).

Without `dpkg-deb` installed (e.g.: in Arch Linux), Archive Manager shows it the way `ar` shows it:

[image]